# PHP: time increment

Tags: php, arrays, time

In my PHP code I have an `array1` that has 2 columns, i.e.:

```
ID | startDate
1  | 2012-02-03 11:50
2  | 2012-02-03 11:50
3  | 2012-02-03 11:50
4  | 2012-02-03 11:50
```

I need to transform `array1` into the following `array2`:

```
ID | startDate
1  | 2012-02-03 11:50:00
2  | 2012-02-03 11:50:30
3  | 2012-02-03 11:51:00
4  | 2012-02-03 11:51:30
```

So, I should just increment a time by 30 seconds starting from the second entry. This increment should be cumulatively propagated as you may see in example. I'm not very fluent in PHP. Does anybody know time-related PHP functions that could do this job in few lines of code?

Comment: You're adding 50 sec, 0 sec, 50 sec, 0 sec etc? They're not 50 sec more each... The 3rd one didn't have 100 sec added. What's the algorithm?

Comment: @Rudie: No, if you look once again at my example, then you see that each record is incremented cumulatively starting from 50 seconds. There is no 0 sec increment for rows 2 and 4.

Comment: The difference between `11:50:50` and `11:51:00` is not 50 seconds, or am I stupid?

Comment: Oh,sorry, Rudie. You are right. Let me update the post.

Comment: Ah, so you do mean 50 seconds each =) That makes it simpler... J.Money is right then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$array2 = array();
$incr = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    $time = strtotime($value);
    $array2[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time + $incr);
    $incr += 30; 
}
```

Comment: It's not 50 sec extra each though... It's 0, 50, 60, 110... So +50, +10, +50.

Comment: @SamDufel In this case, $value will always be the same and therefore $time will always be the same, but if the array values were different you would need to call strtotime every time.

Comment: @Gusgus There are 10 seconds between 11:50:50 and 11:51:00

Comment: What's the difference between 11:50:50 and 11:51:00? It's not 50 seconds, is it? Do you know how many seconds a minute has?

Comment: @Rudie: Sorry once again. I was looking at too many numbers today;)

Comment: No problem. I was actually having doubts... 0, 5, 50, 0, -10 aaaaaaaargh

Comment: @J.Money - I'm not saying to just run the loop with that line omitted.  There are a couple other ways to increment a timestamp.

Comment: @SamDufel - Care to elaborate?

Comment: PHP timestamps are expressed in seconds - you can directly add seconds to a timestamp, or use the DateTime object to add an interval.

Comment: Also, if you're pulling from a mysql database you can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP to get the timestamp directly from a date / timestamp field.

Comment: Creating a DateTime object will still convert the date to a unix timestamp and adding 30 seconds to it won't be as simple as addition. A date can be pulled from the database as a timestamp, but nothing in this question says anything about a database and it would still require converting a date string to a timestamp. I do not agree that you would not want to use strtotime in a loop in this case.